# How do I apply a lambda function on pandas slices, and return the same format as the input data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function  to row slices of dataframe in pandas for each row and returning a dataframe with for each row the value and number of slices that was calculated. 
So, for example

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.round(numpy.random.normal(size=(2, 10)),2))
f = lambda x: (x - x.mean())
```

What I want is to apply lambda function f from column 0 to 5 and from column 5 to 10.
I did this:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame(f(df.T.iloc[0:5,:])
```

but this is only for the first slice.. how can include the second slice in the code, so that my resulting output frame looks exactly as the input frame -- just that every data point is changed to its value minus the mean of the corresponding slice.

I hope it makes sense.. What would be the right way to go with this?

thank you.

Comment: I was thinking that I could do the same for the second slice `b = pandas.DataFrame(f(df.T.iloc[5::,:])` and then concatenate both frames, and than transpose again. However, `concat` takes lists or dictionaries not DataFrames..

Comment: can you edit your provided `df`, it throws `SyntaxError`

Comment: Okay, i did, forgot a bracket. thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question, please see my answer and I will update if it isn't the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply reassign the result to original `df`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# I'd rather use a function than lambda here, preference I guess
def f(x):
    return x - x.mean()


df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.normal(size=(2,10)), 2))

df.T 
      0     1
0  0.92 -0.35
1  0.32 -1.37
2  0.86 -0.64
3 -0.65 -2.22
4 -1.03  0.63
5  0.68 -1.60
6 -0.80 -1.10
7 -0.69  0.05
8 -0.46 -0.74
9  0.02  1.54

# makde a copy of df here
df1 = df

# just reassign the slices back to the copy
# edited, omit DataFrame part.
df1.T[:5], df1.T[5:] = f(df.T.iloc[0:5,:]), f(df.T.iloc[5:,:])

df1.T
       0     1
0  0.836  0.44
1  0.236 -0.58
2  0.776  0.15
3 -0.734 -1.43
4 -1.114  1.42
5  0.930 -1.23
6 -0.550 -0.73
7 -0.440  0.42
8 -0.210 -0.37
9  0.270  1.91
```

Comment: This applies the function the the first slice. Should I then just re-apply the function on the second slice in the same way.. is that the best way to do this? `df.T[5:] = pd.DataFrame(f(df.T.iloc[5:,:]))`

Comment: but if you're making `[5:]`, do you mean you want the new data and calculate a new `x-x.mean()`? Because index **5** is overlapped

Comment: let's see.. I want to apply the function to the slice on columns 0,1,2,3,4 and then also on 5,6,7,8,9. However, I want the function to run on the original data where the mean is taken only from the first 5 in the first round and then on the last 5 in the second round. Does that make sense?

Comment: I thought `iloc[0:5,:]` does not include 5?

Comment: @oaklander114, you're right, I got mixed up with `loc`, answer edited, and Yes, you can just reassign that at one go

Comment: hold on, so if I understand correctly this time, you want the original data to get the mean for first 5, then using the new value to do the last 5?

Comment: no, it's meant to be on the original data, so you're answer is correct! Thanks!

Comment: hmmmm.... it's so weird.. it worked and now it doesn't apply any kind of calculation, even when I take exactly your code.. >>> When I use `df1=df.copy()` it works, but not with `df1=df`.. don't know how that makes sense..

Comment: What I found is that it's not required to write `df1.T[:5], df1.T[5:] = pd.DataFrame(f(df.T.iloc[0:5,:])), pd.DataFrame(f(df.T.iloc[5:,:]))` but just `df1.T[:5], df1.T[5:] = f(df.T.iloc[0:5,:]),f(df.T.iloc[5:,:])` -- Could you adjust that in your answer?

Comment: @oaklander114 I have edited the answer, glad you have tgis sorted :)